# ImageButton con imagen externa

Tags: android, imagen

me preguntaba si alguien podría ayudarme. Estoy tratando de crear un `ImageButton` con una imagen que se encuntre en la memoria interna.

Desde una clase Fragment estoy utilizando este codigo:

```
ImageButton box1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Imagen2);
Drawable drawable = GetImg(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Imagenes/paisaje1.jpg");
box1.setBackground(drawable);

private Drawable GetImg(String url)
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Err="+e); return null;
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_Imagen2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="box1" />
```

Me muestra un mensaje de error `android:src="box1"`  del XML

Como podría cargar una imagen externa en `ImageButton`

**drawable:null**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola,  `android:src` en esta parte se pone la imagen, ej.  `android:src="@drawable/Imagen" `

Comment: Hola @Luis si de ahí se muestra la imagen que se encuentra en la carpeta `drawable`, yo lo que intento mostrar una imagen que se encuentra en el móvil, en lo que android llama la tarjeta memoria externa, no de la SDcard, porque de desde la SDcarg parece que no hay ni dios que sepa como hacerlo.

Comment: @SoCu elimina  android:src="box1"  y trata nuevamente.

Comment: No se que ha pasado, parece que se eliminan comentarios sin previo aviso, lo digo porque esta mañana he puesto un comentario y no lo veo, así que lo volveré a poner..... @Elenasys y compañía, comentaba que en primero  mensaje he puesto una captura donde muestra la imagen como **drawable:null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si obtienes un `Drawable` a partir de una url, el problema es simplemente que no necesitas definir     `android:src` ya que la carga de la imagen se realiza programaticamente, elimina esa propiedad:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_Imagen2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

ahora en tu método debes definir la url no la ruta de una imagen en el directorio externo y es importante no realizar descargas en el hilo principal, para esto puedes usar un AsyncTask:

```
public static ImageButton box1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Url ejemplo de imagen.
    String urlImage = "https://www.android.com/static/2016/img/hero-carousel/banner-android-p-2.jpg";

     box1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);
    GetImg(getApplicationContext(), urlImage);

 }


public static void GetImg(final Context ctx, final String url) {

        new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable>(){

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... strings) {
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "GetImg() : " + e.getMessage());
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), bmp);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

                //Add image to ImageView
                box1.setImageDrawable(result);

            }


        }.execute();

}
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, antes de crear el post también lo intente eliminando esa linea, y la imagen sigue sin mostrarse, ahora he podido utilizar el Debug porque tenia problemas con la ultima actualización del emulador, cuando en una linea pongo un punto rojo para suspender, la aplicación no funciona, ahora he podido ver que **drawable:null** no se si es porque no carga bien la imagen, mira la captura del primer post.

Comment: Espera @SoCu , lo que sucede es que tu método no recibe un path de una imagen en el directorio externo, recibe una url , si deseas cargar una imagen de un URL usa un ASynctask, agregué ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, ya veo que estaba mezclando dos métodos, utilizare ese para mostrar la imagen desde una URL, y el otro que he puesto para mostrar la imagen desde la memoria externa.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues creo que ya puedo mostrar la imagen, en este caso con:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile()
```

Gracias por vuestro interés, aunque sigo sin poder recuperar la imagen desde la memoria externa (MicroSD), supongo que esto es un tema para un nuevo post.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo utilizo de la siguiente manera y me funciona sin problemas ;)

```
BitmapDrawable fondo = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), 
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getPath()));

layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setBackground(fondo);
```

Comment: Hola @PaquiRC Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que revises las recomendaciones de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).